# sqlalchemy execute engine returning Nonetype when try to insert in postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert into a table in my postgres database with sqlalchemy in python and I'm getting error return NoneType object, why? I don't understand.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from db.db import engine

def register_new_item(item_name, item_age, item_dress):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        trans = conn.begin()
        conn.execute(text("""
            INSERT INTO products(
                item_name,
                item_age,
                item_dress
            ) VALUES (
                :item_name,
                :item_age,
                :item_dress
            )               
        """),
            item_name= item_name,
            item_age= item_age,
            item_dress= item_dress
        )
        trans.commit()
        conn.close()
```

error:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**

Answer (score 0):

I findout, for who find this question, what I did:
change the primary key id from INTEGER to SERIAL, to not require that I am pass the field and the db create itself.
return the response inside the function called by the @app.after_request.